# antiderivative of :$f(x)= \left(1-x^2\right)^\frac{1}{m}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to find the antiderivative of the following function :
$$f(x)= \left(1-x^2\right)^\frac{1}{m}$$
where $m \in \mathbb{N}$

I am looking for special cases for example $m=3$, $m=4$, $m=5$.

Please could you help me in finding how could I find the primitive of this function? Is there any particular technique concerning this types of functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try $$(1-x^2)^a=(1-x)^a(1+x)^a$$ and maybe get it into [Incomplete Beta](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) or [Gauss Hypergeometric form](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/) in the links.

Answer (score 0):

Denoting $f(x) = \int_0^x \left(1 - t^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{m}} \, \mathrm{d}t$, by the [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) you know $f$ is an antiderivative you're looking for.
Then
$$
\int_0^x \left(1 - t^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{m}} \, \mathrm{d}t\overset{\color{purple}{u = \frac{t^2}{x^2}}}{=} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{ \left(1 - x^2u \right)^{-\frac{1}{m}}} \frac{x}{2\sqrt{u}} \mathrm{d}u =x\frac{1}{B\left(\color{green}{\frac{1}{2}}, \color{maroon}{\frac{3}{2}}- \color{green}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{\color{green}{\frac{1}{2}} -1}(1-u)^{\color{maroon}{\frac{3}{2}} - \color{green}{\frac{1}{2}} -1}}{ \left(1 - \color{red}{x^2}u \right)^{\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{m}}}} \mathrm{d}u
$$
since $B\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}- \frac{1}{2}\right) = 2$ (with $B(x,y)$ being the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)). But recalling that the [Hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) has integral representation
$$
_2 F_1(\color{blue}{a},\color{green}{b};\color{maroon}{c};\color{red}{z}) = \frac{1}{B(\color{green}{b}, \color{maroon}{c}-\color{green}{b})} \int_0^1\frac{u^{\color{green}{b}-1}(1-u)^{\color{maroon}{c}-\color{green}{b}-1}}{(1-\color{red}{z}u)^{\color{blue}{a}}}\mathrm{d} u
$$
you can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int\left(1 - x^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{m}} \, \mathrm{d}x = x\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};x^2\right) +C}
$$

Comment: How does $t$ reappear after the change of variables? I would also break the first chain of equalities using an align environment to make the presentation clearer.

Comment: Made an error transcribing the Hypergeometric function. Thank you for pointing it out!